# How can I create a Goatperson?

Tags: desktop-dungeons

I've got the special edition of Desktop Dungeons, which includes the Goatperson DLC. As I understand it, among other things this includes a new playable Goatperson class.

I've been playing Desktop Dungeons for a while now and still haven't seen a way to create a Goatperson. Do I have to progress to a certain point before I can unlock it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to unlock the Goatperson, you need to purchase his building at a relatively steep price of 3000 kingdom gold.  The building seems to first appear when you beat the Frozen Tundra quest.  But you'll likely need to keep questing for a while before you can actually purchase it, since your kingdom bank needs to be upgraded to be able to hold that much gold.

Comment: @Sterno It might be Frozen Tundra since I've done the other two on my new game and haven't unlocked it yet.  I'll try to see what I can figure out.

Comment: @Sterno I just unlocked the building when I beat the quest in Frozen Tundra, meaning it was my second time beating the dungeon.  Does that match what you saw?